# SQL: How to combine rows only until certain action/condition/event is triggered

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm dealing with BigQuery, and would like to see the user past behaviour per session, until they reach conversion, which is denoted by `result=1`.

Right now, I will give a table example for **1** user. I would also like to abstract it for all users. Note that `visitId` is UNIQUE to each `fullVisitorId`.

```
#t1
fullVisitorId   visitId    visitNumber     page_views     result     
1               1214       4               11             0
1               112        5               9              0
1               1014       6               10             1
1               1511       7               10             0
1               1614       8               10             1
```

Effectively, I want the query to remove all rows after the first conversion, effectively leaving us with:

```
#t2
fullVisitorId   visitId    visitNumber     page_views     result     
1               1214       4               11             0
1               112        5               9              0
1               1014       6               10             1
```

If there are no conversions for that `fullVisitorId`, then keep all rows. I could use the following SQL to then aggregate this into 1 row:

```
SELECT fullVisitorId,
MAX(visitNumber)-MIN(visitNumber) AS number_visits,
SUM(page_views)/number_visits AS pages_per_s,
FROM t2
GROUP BY fullVisitorId
```

This would give me what I want.

```
#t3_visitor_past
fullVisitorId   number_visits     pages_per_s       
1               3                 10
```

Please keep in mind that I would like to have arbitrary number of different `fullVisitorId`'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in doing the following steps:

1. Find all rows where `result=1` call this `t4`
2. From the table above, run `SELECT fullVisitorId, visitId, MIN(visitNumber) FROM t4` to get the list of first events call this table `t5`
3. Do an inner join: `SELECT * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t5 ON t1.fullVisitorId = t5.fullVisitorId AND t1.visitNumber <= t5.visitNumber`

Same procedure for the NON converted users.